# Convert BIGSERIAL to BIGINT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table defined across two scripts as follows (I'm eliding unneeded details):

```
CREATE TABLE a (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
ALTER TABLE IMAGE ADD COLUMN b_id BIGSERIAL;
```

This results in a table with a column `b_id` that is a `BIGSERIAL`, and is a foreign key to table `b` from `a`. This is incorrect, however, and I need to alter the table (safely) to drop the `SERIAL` part and leave it as a `BIGINT`. (Essentially, that column should not insert an autoincremented number if there is an insert that doesn't specify the value.)

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) indicates that a `SERIAL` just adds a sequence to the underlying datatype, and there are plenty of results for how to do this manually if you want to move from an integer-based type to a serial-based type, but not the reverse. The documentation says:

> You can drop the sequence without dropping the column, but this will
>   force removal of the column default expression.

But the documentation to [`DROP SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-dropsequence.html) is remarkably light in terms of what name to use and what the effects of this are.

- Can I `DROP SEQUENCE b_id` safely to get the result I want (that `b_id` is a simple `BIGINT` column?)
- Do I have to do anything else to get the table into a safe state, without disrupting the values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BIGSERIAL` is already `BIGINT`, it just automatically adds the sequence. You can see it if you do `\d a`. You will see something like this:

```
                         Table "public.a"
 Column |  Type  |                   Modifiers
--------+--------+------------------------------------------------
 id     | bigint | not null default nextval('a_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "a_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

So right there you see the sequence name: `a_id_seq`. So drop that.

```
=# DROP SEQUENCE a_id_seq CASCADE;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to default for table a column id
DROP SEQUENCE

=# \d a
      Table "public.a"
 Column |  Type  | Modifiers
--------+--------+-----------
 id     | bigint | not null
Indexes:
    "a_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Hm. So, I am trying this and am getting `Syntax error in SQL statement "DROP SEQUENCE IMAGE_EXPERIMENT_ID_SEQ CASCADE[*] ";`

Comment: Are you typing a literal `[*] ";` in there? Try it without `CASCADE` if not.

Comment: I am not. `DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS image_experiment_id_seq RESTRICT;` also fails with a syntax error. It's being run with Flyway, though, so maybe that is doing something odd.

Comment: I don't know what Flyway is. Either way, this is correct syntax so I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: http://flywaydb.org/ is to blame, I think. Something is being munged: the syntax works directly. Thanks!

Comment: Specifically, it turns out it was also creating an `h2` database, which does not like either `CASCADE` or `RESTRICT`.